# Following a tutorial, cant figure out my javascript syntax mistake

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I want to change all instances of the word "cão" on a page to read "gato" (following an older tutorial).

All instances of "cão" are inside a span and I´m trying to change them by using getElementsByTagName method.

Since there more than one, I cant use innerHTML to change the content so I´m using a for loop to cycle through all positions but I´m getting a sytax error after the increment i++. Why is that?

```
var elementoHeading = document.getElementById('heading');
elementoHeading.innerHTML = "Tudo sobre gatos";

var nomesTags = document.getElementsByTagName("span");   


for (var i = 0, i < nomesTags.length, i++) {
nomesTags[i].innerHTML = "gato";
}
```

Comment: Use semicolon instead of comma. in forloop syntax. 
for (var i = 0; i < nomesTags.length; i++)

Answer (score 4):

Use semicolons, not commas, in the `for` construct:

```
for (var i = 0; i < nomesTags.length; i++) {
              ^                     ^
```

The reason the syntax error is after the increment is because the JS engine expects 3 statements inside of the `for`'s brackets, but you only gave one (commas don't terminate the statement).